# CakeBake invalid controller

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm generating a controller with cakebake based on table name **cliente_planos**. It generates the controller methods using `$this->ClientePlanos`, is right, but no methods work. They only work if I "fix" this to `$this->Clienteplanos`.

The correct is `$this->ClientePlanos` but it's not working. Am I missing something?

I am using cakephp 3 and PHP 5.6.3

PS:sorry my english

Comment: Are you bake model 'ClientePlanos'?

Comment: yes. Model, Controller and Tests, But error fires in Controller